# Passing parameter results to subreport command

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, parameter-passing, subreport

I have a subreport that will search a table pulling all matches depending on two things. 1.) Some filtering criteria in the command for the subreport and 2.)it will search based on the criteria pulled by a parameter from the main report.

1.) Is this possible? I have tried for a few days now to get this to work but I feel I am missing something. I cannot get the field in the main report to pass the information to the parameter for the command in the subreport.

Here is the command for the subreport.....

```
DECLARE @DIE VARCHAR (20)
SET @DIE = '1315240018'

SELECT DISTINCT BCKUPDIE.TOOL1

FROM FS11HD AS BCKUPDIE

JOIN FS11HD AS ORGDIE 
    ON 
    BCKUPDIE.DIE_SHAPE = ORGDIE.DIE_SHAPE
    AND BCKUPDIE.AROUND1 = ORGDIE.AROUND1
    AND BCKUPDIE.ACROSS1 = ORGDIE.ACROSS1
    WHERE ORGDIE.TOOL1 = @DIE
```

When run in sql it will give me any TOOL1 rows that have matching criteria. This is what I want my subreport to, am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: did you try linking the subreport by the parameter on the main report?

Comment: Yes that was one of my first tries but I ran into several issues doing that.....
 How am I suppesed to "SET" the declared variable as a parameter coming from the main report? More importantly what is the syntax?

Secondly, when i got rid of the declare and just used where, I was unable to assign the variable to that command statement

Comment: Lastly, when I try to change subreport links my declare @die never shows up so that I can link that with my dies field from the main report

Answer (score 0):

We have an old version of Crystal report (XI) but the logic might be the same with your version.

On the menu select [Edit] [Subreport Links].

Select the sub report from the pick list then map your select choices to the sub reports selection criteria.

On the sub report you will have to have parameter fields that will match the values up with the values you wish to pass.  Such as if you select date as a selection criteria on the main report and you want the sub report to also filter by this date create a date pram in the sub report.  By linking all the select criteria with [linked] values it will behave as a straight through pass of the parameters without a prompt box being all have been answered via the linkage between documents.

Comment: Ok so after doing this I was able to pull the parameter field into the subreport but how am I able to use the parameter in my sql command? Or, is there a good website to either convert or learn whatever language crystal uses in it's formula window?

Comment: Now on your record selection editor modify this to pass your pass-through values such as: table.fld = {?passed}, or depending on how you set up the selector it can be as simple as : {@Filter} and all the filtering is manipulated via a function within the report.

Comment: Once you got the values to pass down to the sub report you are 99% the way there.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you took difficult path to achive your requirement, Try below solution I hope this will be easy to implement.

Firstly remove the `@Die`  from command instead pass the `@Die` value from main report as part of formula field.

your subreport query will be changed to

```
SELECT DISTINCT BCKUPDIE.TOOL1

FROM FS11HD AS BCKUPDIE

JOIN FS11HD AS ORGDIE 
    ON 
    BCKUPDIE.DIE_SHAPE = ORGDIE.DIE_SHAPE
    AND BCKUPDIE.AROUND1 = ORGDIE.AROUND1
    AND BCKUPDIE.ACROSS1 = ORGDIE.ACROSS1
```

In main report create a formula `@Die` and enter data as `'1315240018'`.

Now link main report and sub report and in linking pass the `@Die` formula and your main report parameter to sub report, By this you have these as parameters in sub report.

In record selection of sub report write as below.

```
ORGDIE.TOOL1 = ?Die //value passed from main report
and your parameter linking
```

By this your filtering criteria will be added to the sub report query.

This should work let me know incase any error

Comment: Actually the data for "Die" will need to come from a field in the report once it is run. Die is a field in that report that is selected the main report. I'm going to try creating a formula where Die would equal that field hopefully that will work.

Comment: Also,why was this the hard way? I am fairly new to sql and report writing but thinking it through the process made sense and seemed pretty straight forward could it be that I don't understand the software that well? Or maybe it's limtations made things more dificult?

Comment: Reason I told it was hard way was you are trying to implement functionality at database level which can be implemented in crystal reports, Though I am not saying it is wrong but my idea is if something that can be done at tool level then better to use tool functioanlity so that life becomes easier